# Can't get plain old many-to-one nested form to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm on Rails 3. I have a model `Client` that has an `address_id`. In my `Client` form, I have nested `Address` fields. Here's that the `Address` part of the form:

```
  <%= f.fields_for @client.address do |address_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= address_form.label :line1 %><br />
      <%= address_form.text_field :line1 %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= address_form.label :line2 %><br />
      <%= address_form.text_field :line2 %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= address_form.label :city %><br />
      <%= address_form.text_field :city %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= address_form.label :state_id %><br />
      <%= select("client[address]", "state_id", State.all.collect {|s| [ s.name, s.id ] }) %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= address_form.label :zip %><br />
      <%= address_form.text_field :zip %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

When I try to save my form, I get this:

```
Address(#23652762896420) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#23652751466220)
```

I don't understand exactly what that means or why I'm getting it. Here's what `params.inspect` looks like:

```
{"commit"=>"Update Client",
 "authenticity_token"=>"CBw1fQcsUtXs9x6lKTL4zeoekX1cwuFUrZvZpCShHIc=",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "utf8"=>"\342\234\223",
 "action"=>"update",
 "id"=>"16",
 "client"=>{"name"=>"Rosie O'Donnell",
            "address"=>{"city"=>"Grand Rapids",
                        "line1"=>"216 Grandville Ave SW",
                        "zip"=>"49503",
                        "line2"=>"",
                        "state_id"=>"1"},
            "phone"=>"",
            "salon_id"=>"1",
            "email"=>""},
 "controller"=>"clients"}
```

Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-object-forms (It's a Rails 2.3 article, but it should apply to Rails 3 as well)

In your `Client` model you need this line:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :address`

Also, change the first line of your nested form to this:

`<%= f.fields_for :address do |address_form| %>`

Comment: When I do `:address` instead of `@client.address`, where does `:address` come from?

Comment: Rails already knows that it has a nested `:address` attribute, and since you're calling it out within the `Client` form, it knows to assign it to the client. Similarly, your `create` controller method doesn't need to explicitly create the address record -- just doing a `@client.save` will save it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following in your clients class:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

and

```
attr_accessible :address_attributes
```

I would modify the form as follows:

```
<%= f.fields_for :address do |address_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= address_form.label :line1 %><br />
    <%= address_form.text_field :line1 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= address_form.label :line2 %><br />
    <%= address_form.text_field :line2 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= address_form.label :city %><br />
    <%= address_form.text_field :city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= address_form.label :state_id %><br />
    <%= select("client[address]", "state_id", State.all.collect {|s| [ s.name, s.id ] }) %>       </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= address_form.label :zip %><br />
    <%= address_form.text_field :zip %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```